# Rapid picture updating causes button click unresponsive in MFC

Tags: mfc

I have a MFC dialog based application with a picture control and some buttons on the dialog. I register the button click using:
ON_BN_CLICKED(IDC_BUTTON_START, OnBnClickedButtonStart);
If I update the picture in OnPaint() using StretchBlt() at about 10 to 30 pictures per second triggered from calling Invalidate() inside a worker thread, the button click stops being responsive. 
Is there way to get around this? Thank you.

Comment: `Invalidate` shouldn't do that, since it only generates `WM_PAINT` messages when the message queue is empty. Are you sure you aren't using `RedrawWindow`?

Comment: On second thought, having any thread except the main one interact with a window is a bad idea that will lead to grief. Have the thread post a custom message to the window, which can call `Invalidate` in the message handler.

Comment: Thank you Mark. I figured out now. It was due to the picture control capturing the focus. I'll take your advice on calling Invalidate(). Thank you. Bin

Comment: Please provide the code for your `WM_PAINT` handler. `StretchBlt` is always a candidate, where one easily introduces a resource leak.